# What DLLs to add to my Visual Studio 2017 project?

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2017

I have a C++ project compiled on Windows 8.1 that doesn't work on some computers. On another Windows 8.1 machine it doesn't open because it's missing a DLL file api-ms-win-core-*. On Windows 7 machines it crashes with a BEX error.

I link dynamically against the runtime library (Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)) and include the following DLLs in the same folder as my executable:

- msvcp140.dll
- ucrtbase140.dll
- vcruntime140.dll

Is there anything else I should include?

Comment: You should use the vcredist package that is included with your toolset. I haven't seen the MS layout for VS2017, but if history has taught us anything, it's usually maintained in the redist folder under the VC install dir (which is usually under the VS install dir). The days of manually packing runtime DLL's should be long gone. Don't try to resurrect them.

Comment: Have a read of: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299.aspx

Comment: Do not distribute ucrtbase.dll, it is part of the OS and maintained by Windows Update.  Having the wrong version present produces these kind of runtime errors.